# durandals routing problems using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I am using an architecture in my proj using durandal , knockoutjs. I have made some changes to the architecture of durandal. I am loading 3 views in same page instead of single page. The problem I am facing is that wen I go to a page and hit back button my previous view is nt loaded.

I have a list, navigation and content parts in my architecture.

my url is

## ABCD/?seeHash=1&c=undefined

When i click on some menu the url becomes

## ABCD/?seeHash=1&c=xyz(my viewmodel)

again when i click other menu the url changes

## ABCD/?seeHash=1&c=LMN(viewmodel)

but now when i click the back button

the url changes back to

## ABCD/?seeHash=1&c=XYZ

but the view doesnt load

Comment: Can you explain more how you are loading 3 views?  The back button is controlled by the router plugin so navigating back a page will only work for the module you have mapped to that route.  I don't see a way that durandal could know that you have 3 modules/views tied to the same route.

Comment: so what does your router.map function look like, are you mapping just the ABCD hash?  If you are already having problems with this setup you might want to consider using the standard composition binding in durandal to show multiple modules/views on a page: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html